# how will select arrays

Tags: php, arrays

i am having an o/p like this.this contains empty array values also,i want to get an array containing non zero values.

```
array
          0 => string 'Account' (length=7)
          1 => string 'Description: CURRENT' (length=20)
          2 => string 'A/C' (length=3)
          3 => string '-' (length=1)
          4 => string 'COLLECTION' (length=10)
          5 => string 'A/C' (length=3)

        array
     0 => string 'Branch' (length=6)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string '' (length=0)
      4 => string '' (length=0)
      5 => string '' (length=0)
      6 => string '' (length=0)
      7 => string '' (length=0)
      8 => string '' (length=0)
      9 => string '' (length=0)
      10 => string '' (length=0)
      11 => string '' (length=0)
      12 => string '' (length=0)
      13 => string ':   SMART' (length=7)
      14 => string 'CITY' (length=4)
i want to get  an array(without empty fields)

 i want to get o/p like this $array=['Account','Description:,A/C,'Branch']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) as

```
$new_array = array_filter($old_array);
```

Comment: when we parse csv into arrays,i am getting horizontal layout arrays,i want it vertically ,how will i do that.